String_Split With Double Reverse Query
I am looking to splitting a string like this:
Select top 1 value 
from string_split(Reverse('test,is,what,this,is'),',')`

I basically want just the last value after the comma in the string, but the string can have an unknown number of comma-delimited values so reversing it and splitting it was the easiest, but now i want to reverse the string back to normal.
I was trying the following query but every variation I tried makes an error:
Select Reverse(Select top 1 value from string_split(Reverse('test,is,what,this,is'),','))

I am using SQLserver
Any idea how to make this work?
The result should be 'is' in this query. Just looking to extract the last value after the last comma.

Maybe you can post your error too? so other can more understand what the problem is.

what database is this for the tag "sql" isn't sufficient to tell us what syntax to propose - is it SQL Server?

Given that you're using REVERSE, you're probably not looking for a solution in SQLite - what SQL dialect are you using? The string_split does indeed suggest MS SQL Server, but you should confirm and let us know if you need a solution that only works on SQL Server5 or is more broadly applicable.

What is the expected result? Are you expecting "is" (the last word in the string) as your result? Please edit the question to include the expected result, and then add the database tag instead of "sql"

TOP (n)/ LIMIT n / FETCH FIRST n ROWS give you the first rows. Without an ORDER BY clause, however, it is completely arbitrary which rows the DBMS happens to pick first.

Have you considered not using delimited strings? It screams of a poor design.

IF you use SQL server (as indicated by top and string_split) then perhaps this will help.
Select top(1) value 
from string_split('test,is,what,this,is',',', 1)
order by ordinal DESC
;

Note this requires the third parameter to string_split (ref) that supplies the column ordinal - and once you have that column you can specify the order using that column. Using the descending order allows choosing just the last word when combined with top(1)
see this fiddle

Why do you need to split string just to get the last value?
One way to do this if you're sitting on older SQL Server version is via charindex:
select right(yourstring, nullif(charindex(',', reverse(yourstring))-1, -1))


You reverse your string and try to find the first ",".
After doing that, we want to take the characters after the comma, for this reason i substract 1 from the charindex.
To protect against "," not found, i use a NULLIF which converts the expression to NULL.
Finally, you take the RIGHT x-characters which returns the right-most string


"The standard way is to do a charindex". It's only the standard way because string_split() with an ordinal column in the result set is of a newer vintage (documentation says SQL 2022) which would enable its consistent use. The fact that we'd been banging rocks together before that doesn't invalidate approaches that do what they say on the tin. By your reasoning, we never should've moved past assembly since we had (in theory) a standard way to do anything.

I think it's kind of a stretch, because i'd say it's a waste to use string_split to get the last value, would you use it to get the value before first char too? But sure, i can change it to the wording up a bit


Need to create below function first.
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Csplit]
 (@str varchar(7850),@code varchar(10),@no int )  
RETURNS varchar(600)
AS  
BEGIN 
    declare @intLen int
    declare @count int
    declare @indexb  int
    declare @indexe  int
    set @intLen=len(@code)
    set @count=0
    set @indexb=1

    if @no=0
      if charindex(@code,@str,@indexb)<>0
         return left(@str,charindex(@code,@str,@indexb)-1) 
      else
         return @str

    while charindex(@code,@str,@indexb)<>0
    begin
        set @count=@count+1
        if @count=@no
            break
        set @indexb=@intLen+charindex(@code,@str,@indexb)
    end 

    if @count=@no
    begin
        set @indexe=@intLen+charindex(@code,@str,@indexb)
            if charindex(@code,@str,@indexe)<>0
                return substring(@str,charindex(@code,@str,@indexb)+len(@code),charindex(@code,@str,@indexe)-charindex(@code,@str,@indexb)-len(@code))
            else 
                return right(@str,len(@str)-charindex(@code,@str,@indexb)-len(@code)+1)
    end

    return ''

END


Run below script.
declare @string_input varchar(200)

set @string_input = 'test,is,what,this,isnot'

select dbo.csplit(@string_input,',',len(@string_input)-len(replace(@string_input,',','')))




This is not going to perform well. The function won't be inlinable (which is a performance issue), and uses iteration, which is also a performance issue. This solution is best avoided. If you had to implement your own function to achieve this an inline table value function would be significantly better.

I've located the answer:
select top (1) value
from STRING_SPLIT('test,is,what,this,is', ',') order by ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) desc

This query provides me with the answer of 'is' I needed

This is a bad idea.STRING_SPLIT is explicitly documented to not guarentee the order of the data returned, and ordering by an arbitrary value (such as NULL) does not change that. You could just easily get the 2nd, or the 4th value here, not the last.
